# Is it possible to have a trigger execute when updating a views query

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers, ddl-trigger

I would like to have a function fire when a person has updated a Views query. What I mean by this is that when a SQL user has edited the view and saved it, I want the trigger to fire. NOT when a SQL user has run an UPDATE query against the view, to fire.

Is this possible? If so, can someone show me an example/point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I believe what I need is a DDL trigger. If anyone has some examples of these, I'd be grateful :)